# tensorflow2 split dataset into two datasets by column names

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to split a tensorflow2 dataset into two datasets such that one contains "features" and another one contains "labels".

In the dataset, each element is a python dictionary:

```
{'id': 29, 'val1': [0.97, 0.52], 'val2': [627], 'val3': ['baseball', 'football', 'basketball'], 'label': 1.0}

{'id': 11, 'val1': [0.22, 0.36], 'val2': [81], 'val3': ['swimming', 'running', 'jumpoing'], 'label': 0.0}
```

The dataset is a prefetched dataset, which is loaded from 1000 txt (.gz) files.
Each file has size 500KB-600KB.
All file data cannot be loaded to memory so I have to prefetch it by batch (size is 200).

```
def a_func(file_paths, batch_size=200):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(file_paths, compression_type='GZIP')
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(batch_size)
    #split the dataset into features and labels ? 
    label = dataset.map(lambda x: col for col in x if col=='label') # error: "x" not defined
    features = dataset.map(lambda x: col for col in x if col!='label')
    return features, label
```

How to split the dataset into two datasets by column names ?

**UPDATE**

```
ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(file_paths, compression_type='GZIP')

type(ds)
# tensorflow.python.data.ops.readers.TFRecordDatasetV2

label = ds.map(lambda x: x['label'])

# TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got 'label'

for row in ds:
    print(row.numpy()) # show a lot of hex chars
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create dummy data
ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(({'id': 11, 'val1': [0.22, 0.36], 'val2': [81], 'val3': ['swimming', 'running', 'jumpoing'], 'label': 0.0}))
ds2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(({'id': 29, 'val1': [0.97, 0.52], 'val2': [627], 'val3': ['baseball', 'football', 'basketball'], 'label': 1.0}))
ds = ds1.concatenate(ds2)

label = ds.map(lambda x: x['label'])
features = ds.map(lambda x: (x['id'], x['val1'], x['val2'], x['val3']))

for l in label:
  print(l)
for f in features:
  print(f)
```

```
tf.Tensor(0.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=11>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.22, 0.36], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([81], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=string, numpy=array([b'swimming', b'running', b'jumpoing'], dtype=object)>)
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=29>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.97, 0.52], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([627], dtype=int32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=string, numpy=array([b'baseball', b'football', b'basketball'], dtype=object)>)
```

Or with dynamic keys:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Create dummy data
ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(({'id': 11, 'val1': [0.22, 0.36], 'val2': [81], 'val3': ['swimming', 'running', 'jumpoing'], 'label': 0.0}))
ds2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(({'id': 29, 'val1': [0.97, 0.52], 'val2': [627], 'val3': ['baseball', 'football', 'basketball'], 'label': 1.0}))
ds = ds1.concatenate(ds2)

label = ds.map(lambda x: x['label'])
features = ds.map(lambda x: (list(map(x.get, list(np.setdiff1d(list(x.keys()),['label']))))))
```

Comment: please see my updates in OP. thanks

Comment: Can you iterate through `ds` and show what one output looks like? @user3448011

Comment: I tried to print out ds, but got many hex chars.

Comment: Ok so that is clearly the problem @user3448011. You said the following in your question: "In the dataset, each element is a python dictionary", where are these dictionaries? How do you know if they are even there?

Comment: @AloneTpgether, I am trying to call tf2 mode.fit() (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

Comment: I need to create a dataset that is a tuple of (inputs, targets), here "inputs" are the "features" and "targets" are "labels".  but, if I return (features, label) from the function in OP, I got error: "Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'tuple'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.MapDataset'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>"